# Could not find configuration node: settings/setting[@name='mediaFolder']/@value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I upgraded sitecore from 7.1 to 7.2 and changed all the configurtion files as stated and getting error Could not find configuration node: settings/setting[@name='mediaFolder']/@value". But my webconfig has following values

```
<setting name="MediaFolder" value="$(mediaFolder)" />
<sc.variable name="mediaFolder" value="/upload" />
 <media>
  <folder ref="settings/setting[@name='mediaFolder']/@value">
  </folder>
  <filter>*</filter>
</media>

The stacktrace
```

> Could not find configuration node:
>   settings/setting[@name='mediaFolder']/@value
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find
>   configuration node: settings/setting[@name='mediaFolder']/@value
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node:
>   settings/setting[@name='mediaFolder']/@value]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, String message)
>   +70    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, String format, Object[] args) +82
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetConfigNode(String xpath, Boolean
>   assert) +281    Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String
>   configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +158
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +203
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +161
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +64
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +461
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, Boolean
>   assert) +61    Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetString(String
>   configPath, Boolean assert) +63
>   Sitecore.IO.FileWatcher..ctor(String configReference) +222
>   Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher..ctor() +50
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1122
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr,
>   Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[]
>   activationAttributes) +128    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args,
>   CultureInfo culture) +18
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[]
>   args) +60
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1
>   moduleList) +189
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +950
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +82
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9948312 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was Sitecore.ContentSearch.config was missing '<' for the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

The setting is case sensitive. Change your reference to this:

```
<folder ref="settings/setting[@name='MediaFolder']/@value">
</folder>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but didn't help. I changed it to <folder ref="settings/setting[@name='MediaFolder']/@value"> but still getting error

Comment: The `<media>` node is surrounded by the `<watchers>` node, right?  I didn't see it in your example, but you may have just trimmed it.

Comment: Are you patching these configs through a separate file or some kind of transform?  Are you sure they are being placed properly?  For example, the `<setting>` is inside `<settings>`, etc?

Comment: I've updated web.config manually after the update.All the config entries are placed in the correct place as well.

Comment: Are you able to save the results of the /admin/showconfig.aspx to a file and share it?

Comment: It is an application error so /admin/showconfig.aspx is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

You may also run into such issues during a bad copy/paste. That is, while all of the characters look fine to the human eye, one or more are not. Try retyping and copied configs / settings by hand.